# Run both express and apache on localhost

Tags: apache, express, http, localhost, port

I am creating a website, which will have two subdomains: texts.example.org and users.example.org

texts.example.org is written in PHP on Apache.

users.example.org is written with express.js.

On a normal server, this is fine. However, I want to be able to run this on my local machine (Windows 10) as well.

I setup subdomains in `.../etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       texts.localhost.local
127.0.0.1       users.localhost.local
```

However, I can't have both Apache and Express.js listening to the same port. How do I tell Apache to only respond to requests for texts.localhost.local, and tell Express to only respond to requests.localhost.local, while sharing a port?

Comment: You could run a proxy like Nginx that listens on your one port and then, based on the requested host, it forwards the requests to the appropriate server (that is listening on some other port).  It's also possible that Apache could serve as the proxy itself (I don't know Apache very well) either keeping the request for your PHP app or forwarding it to your express app on another port.

Comment: @jfriend00 Can you explain how to do that? I would prefer not to involve a third program, but if necessary I am willing to do so.

Comment: Explain how to do what?  How to set up nginx?

Comment: @jfriend00 preferably, how to set up Apache as the proxy, but sure, how to set up nginx as a proxy as well

Comment: Well, setting up NGINX as a proxy is all covered in the documentation.  We could help better if you read the doc, tried to set it up yourself and then post a new question if you get stuck on something specific.  I already told you I don't know any of the details about Apache, just its general capabilities.